# How to fill left region of the plot with red and right region with yellow?

Tags: plotting, filling

```
ListLogPlot[{{95.90081`, 0.5562`}, {96.28275`, 0.66891`}, {96.10102`, 
   0.74037`}, {96.66512`, 0.81191`}, {96.48471`, 
   0.92386`}, {96.67568`, 1.01315`}, {96.86841`, 1.15284`}, {96.6858`,
    1.25267`}, {96.69768`, 1.60703`}, {95.95647`, 
   1.78698`}, {96.14612`, 1.90618`}, {95.40249`, 
   2.01475`}, {96.71132`, 2.13915`}, {98.58359`, 
   2.45645`}, {100.45674`, 2.87336`}, {101.5823`, 
   3.26938`}, {102.33692`, 3.89568`}, {102.7171`, 
   4.51531`}, {102.53757`, 5.23364`}, {101.98183`, 
   5.68693`}, {102.54945`, 6.71417`}, {102.36817`, 
   7.50032`}, {102.74526`, 8.14959`}, {102.74966`, 
   8.93728`}, {102.56617`, 9.53363`}, {103.31464`, 
   9.98339`}, {103.50869`, 11.67867`}, {103.51749`, 
   14.04538`}, {103.52453`, 16.27966`}, {103.53333`, 
   19.57876`}, {103.72737`, 22.90342`}, {103.7331`, 
   25.82209`}, {103.55181`, 28.84556`}, {103.55665`, 
   31.92684`}, {103.37558`, 35.83003`}, {103.57337`, 
   45.33377`}, {103.57997`, 52.06271`}, {103.58657`, 
   59.79044`}, {103.59405`, 69.94403`}}, Joined -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> {{80, 300}, {0.55, 55}}, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 20]]
```

Comment: Interesting question.  One would think that Mma would readily enable the use of `Filling` to the `Left` or `Right` y axis, but the documentation specifies, `Filling` as "... an option for ListPlot, Plot, Plot3D, and related functions that specifies what filling to add **under** points, curves, and surfaces."  Filling has no provision to fill to the side.  Unless doing so would have unintended consequences I don't recognize, this could make an excellent feature request.

Comment: A not good answer (but kind of funny) `// Rasterize // Binarize // MorphologicalComponents // Colorize`, so put as a comment.

Answer (score 5):

**1.** You can

1. `Reverse` the coordinates of your input list (`lst`),
2. Use `ListLogLinearPlot` with bottom and top fillings,
3. Flip the coordinates of graphics primitives using `ReflectionTransform`
4. `Show` the result with options from your original plot.

```
llp = ListLogPlot[lst, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Black, 
  PlotRange -> {{80, 300}, {0.55, 55}}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 20]]


lllp = ListLogLinearPlot[{#, #} &@Map[Reverse]@lst, Joined -> True, 
   PlotStyle -> {Black, None}, 
   PlotRange -> Reverse@{{80, 300}, {0.55, 55}}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 20], 
   Filling -> {1 -> {Bottom, Yellow}, 2 -> {Top, Red}}];

Show[lllp /. prims : (_Line | _Polygon | _Point) :> 
   GeometricTransformation[prims, ReflectionTransform[{1, -1}]], 
 llp[[2]]]
```

[image]

**2.** Alternatively, define a function for post-processing `ListLogPlot` output to add desired filling polygons:

```
ClearAll[addHorizontalFilling]
addHorizontalFilling[filling : {{_, _} ..}][g_Graphics] := 
 ReplaceAll[g, l : Line[x_] :> {GeometricTransformation[
       First@ListLinePlot[Reverse /@ x, 
         Filling -> (# /. {Left -> Bottom, Right -> Top}), 
         FillingStyle -> #2, PlotRange -> Reverse[PlotRange[g]]], 
       ReflectionTransform[{1, -1}]] & @@@ filling, l}]


addHorizontalFilling[{{Left, Yellow}, {Right, Red}}] @ llp
```

[image]

**3.** Yet another method: Post-process `llp` to add two polygons constructed using the coordinates of line objects:

```
llp /. l : Line[x_] :> 
 {{Red, 
   Polygon[Join[x, {Scaled[{1, 1}, First @ x], Scaled[{1, 0}, First @ x]}]], 
   Yellow, 
   Polygon[Join[x, {Scaled[{-1, 1}, First @ x], Scaled[{-1, 0}, First @ x]}]]}, 
   l}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following. Let lst be your list. Then try

```
Show[{
  ListLogPlot[Join[{{50, 0.1}, {95, 0.1}}, lst], Joined -> True, 
   PlotStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> {{80, 300}, {0.55, 55}}, 
   Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 20], Filling -> Top, 
   FillingStyle -> LightYellow],
  ListLogPlot[Join[lst, {{103.6, 55}, {300, 55}}], Joined -> True, 
   PlotStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> {{80, 300}, {0.55, 55}}, 
   Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 20], 
   Filling -> Bottom, FillingStyle -> LightRed]
  }]
```

with the following effect:

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you so much.